# Why is my WCF service not working in Test Project?

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing

Something strange is happening.  I have a WCF service using C# and Visual Studio 2015 up and running.

This service is published to my local IIS and I have a test website where I can consume my services and display results.  The website is running in the visual studio IIS on a generated port.

I have a test project which is where I'm experiencing a problem.  In the test project I run the same code that works in the website.  However when I debug it my wcf result is already out of context.

- The test fails
- The service result 'does not exist in the current context' when debugging.

  > ```
  >     [TestMethod]
  >     public void Test_GetListOfFastPlans()
  >     {
  >         FastPlanFileShareServiceClient client = new FastPlanFileShareServiceClient();
  >
  >         ListSharedFastPlansResult thisismyresult = client.ListOfSharedFastPlans("asdf", "asdf", null, null, null, false);
  >
  >         Assert.IsTrue(thisismyresult.ServiceResult.WasSuccessful);
  >     }
  > ```

I can step through the entire code block from creating the client to making the call and finally the assertion without any errors.  however, the resultclass and the client are never in context.

I don't know what is happening or how to diagnosis the issues.

Comment: maybe problem with app.config?

Comment: the app.config is identical to the web.config from the website I also use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out I was running in Release mode.  When I switched it to Debug mode I was able to get context on my objects and step through the code as expected.  I have not researched this in detail, if anyone has a specific reason on why a proxy service does this please add it.

Answer (score 0):

I used proxy in my server And that created a problem.by deleting Proxy problem is solved.